# Массив из дивов jQuery

Tags: jquery

Мне надо чтобы при выборе определеной опции в селекте, показывался определенный див с контентом, а остальные дивы с контентом не отображались.
Написал такой код, но это полное г хотя и работает.
Поправьте пожалуйста, не могу понять логику, как сделать чтобы была нормальная функция и массивы, если я конечно в правильном направлении мыслю.

```js
 <script>
      $('#select').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value == 'wwwsel') {
    $('#www').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#regular').css('display', 'none');
    $('#banners').css('display', 'none');
    $('#adult').css('display', 'none');
    $('#eshop').css('display', 'none');
  }
  if (value == 'eshopsel') {
    $('#eshop').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#regular').css('display', 'none');
    $('#banners').css('display', 'none');
    $('#adult').css('display', 'none');
    $('#www').css('display', 'none');
  }
  if (value == 'bannerssel') {
    $('#banners').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#regular').css('display', 'none');
    $('#www').css('display', 'none');
    $('#adult').css('display', 'none');
    $('#eshop').css('display', 'none');
  }
  if (value == 'adultsel') {
    $('#adult').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#regular').css('display', 'none');
    $('#banners').css('display', 'none');
    $('#www').css('display', 'none');
    $('#eshop').css('display', 'none');
  }
  if (value == 'regularsel') {
    $('#regular').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#www').css('display', 'none');
    $('#banners').css('display', 'none');
    $('#adult').css('display', 'none');
    $('#eshop').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="works">
<select id="select">
 <option value="wwwsel"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">WWW</a></option>
 <option value="eshopsel"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">E-SHOP</a></option>
 <option value="bannerssel"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">BANNERS</a></option>
 <option value="adultsel"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">ADULT</a></option>
 <option value="regularsel" selected><a class="dropdown-item" href="">REGULAR</a></option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div id="gallery-thumbs" class="row">
  <div style="display: inherit;" class="row" id="regular">
   <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="row" id="eshop">
   <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="row" id="www">
   <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="row" id="banners">
   <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" class="row" id="adult">
   <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/render1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="views"><a href="portfolio.html" class="more">VIEW MORE</a></div>
</div>
<div class="arch container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="arch_field">
  <a href="architecture.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/arch.png"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#gallery-thumbs > .row").addClass("hidden");
  $("#" + value).removeClass("hidden");
});
$('#select').change();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="works">
  <select id="select">
    <option value="www"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">WWW</a></option>
    <option value="eshop"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">E-SHOP</a></option>
    <option value="banners"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">BANNERS</a></option>
    <option value="adult"><a class="dropdown-item" href="">ADULT</a></option>
    <option value="regular" selected><a class="dropdown-item" href="">REGULAR</a></option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="gallery-thumbs" class="row">
  <div class="row" id="regular">regular
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  regular</div>
  <div class="row" id="eshop">eshop
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  eshop</div>
  <div class="row" id="www">www
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  www</div>
  <div class="row" id="banners">banners
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  banners</div>
  <div class="row" id="adult">adult
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/render1.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work2.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="img/work3.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  adult</div>
</div>

<div class="views"><a href="portfolio.html" class="more">VIEW MORE</a></div>
</div>
<div class="arch container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="arch_field">
      <a href="architecture.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/arch.png"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @Vadim Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // дивы должны иметь класс по которому вы можете их выбрать все и спрятать
    // на текущий момент это класс `row` но вы можете добавить какой-то специфический
    // чтобы не выбрать другие НЕнужные элементы с таким же классом
    $('.row').css('display', 'none');     
    $('#' + value).css('display', 'inherit');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!